# rosrun will not execute despite successful build

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a successful catkin_make, I made sure to source devel/setup.bash inside the catkin workspace and ran roscore.
The output of echo "$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" is "/home/alex/kinect_bench/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks".

I get his warning from catkin_make:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/strstream:52:0,
             from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkIOStream.h:112,
             from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkSystemIncludes.h:40,
             from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkIndent.h:24,
             from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkObjectBase.h:43,
             from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkSmartPointerBase.h:26,
             from /usr/include/vtk-5.8/vtkSmartPointer.h:23,
             from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/point_cloud_geometry_handlers.h:48,
             from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/point_cloud_handlers.h:41,
             from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/common/actor_map.h:40,
             from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h:47,
             from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h:39,
             from /home/alex/kinect_bench/src/grabber/src/openni_grabber.cpp:2:

/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/backward_warning.h:33:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
```

also, when I run roswtf the output is:

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf No package or stack in context
================================================================================ Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/home/alex/kinect_bench/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages] point to a directory:   * /home/alex/kinect_bench/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

================================================================================ Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile... analyzing graph... ... done analyzing graph running graph rules... ... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s). Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:  * /rosout:    * /rosout
```

my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(grabber)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_msgs
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES grabber
  CATKIN_DEPENDS pcl_conversions pcl_msgs pcl_ros roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

#add_library(grabber
#  src/${PROJECT_NAME}/grabber.cpp
#)

# target_link_libraries(grabber_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (grabber src/openni_grabber.cpp)
target_link_libraries (grabber ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

my package.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>grabber</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The grabber package</description>
  <maintainer email="alex@todo.todo">alex</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_conversions</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_conversions</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
 </package>
```

Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194985/rosrun-will-not-execute-despite-successful-build/) by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-14**:
What is the exact command that is failing? is it `rosrun grabber grabber` ?

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2014-10-14**:
the failing command is `rosrun grabber openni_grabber` openni_grabber is the file located at `~/kinect_bench/src/grabber/src/openni_grabber.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `add_executable(grabber src/openni_grabber.cpp)` line in your CMakeLists is creating an executable named `grabber`. Therefore, the correct command to run your program is:

```
rosrun grabber grabber
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2